# How do I get a JSON object from an Http Response?

Tags: json, angular, http

I have the following api call in my service:

```
    getData()  {
    return this.http.post<Object>(this.base_URL + "web_app/login/", JSON.stringify(this.login))

  .subscribe(response=>{    
    console.log(response);

  })
```

The response is an object with two attributes, access_token and Success. I get the following in my console:

```
{access_token: "...", Success: "Success"}
Success: "Success"
access_token:"..."
```

When I try to access the access_token attribute, using response.access_token, I get an error. Why is this and how do I fix it? Is the response I'm getting an object? Thank you!

Edit: this is what console gives 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwiAm.jpg)

Comment: 1) What is the error you are talking about ? 2) Are you sure that this is the full and only output of your console log you are showing here ? If so, it seems your api does return some mix of a json followed by 2 lines of text,

Comment: Note: If your API returns a json, then angular `http`methods like `get` or `post` will automatically deserialize it for you to a Javascript object. Otherwise it would consider it like a big string, if I remember correctly. Can you modify your API so that it actually returns a simple JSON ?

Comment: Are you using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)? By default it receives and returns JSON. Check this guide:  https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data

Comment: Also, unless your backend so requires, you don't need to stringify your JSON payload.

Comment: @MondKin that was a remnant of some earlier debugging, still have the same issue without the stringify. I am using HttpClient. If it returns JSON why can't I access it's properties?

Comment: can you post what is the object you get when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: @Sajeetharan posted!

Comment: If you use httpClient (not the old and deprecated http) you needn't use JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your image shows you are getting the response on console, try accessing it as follows,

```
.subscribe(response=>{    
    console.log(response['access_token']);
  })
```